# Javascript regex to parse string like "string1[string2][string3]" to array

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to parse a string like the one below, by using regexp in Javascript:

```
string1[string2][string3]
```

In which "string1" is always present, meanwhile the other strings can miss, be 2 or be 20, but always each one between square brackets.
The result I want to achieve from the previous string is an array or something like this:

```
['string1', 'string2', 'string3']
```

I manage to create a regexp, but it just takes the last string "string3" between square brackets and not all of them, this is what I tried:

```
/[^\[]+(\[([^\]]+)\]){0,}/
```

Hope someone can help.

Thanks!

Comment: what about this situation : `string1[string2[str]][string3]`

Comment: Split with `/[\][]+/`

Comment: You can not do it in javascript. Try others' solutions.

Comment: Hi passion, no I can't have that situation, is an arbitrary string it can only be like this: `string1[string2[str]][string3]`.
revo I can do it with an iteration and substrings, but I would like to use regex because I think are more "clean" for this job.
Thanks Wiktor I'll try your solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simplest would be just to use:

```
([^\[\]]+)
```

which basically just takes whatever string that doesn't have square brackets in it: https://regex101.com/r/uS5bZ2/1

However you might get into trouble if the text contains stray `[` or `]`, such as `'string1[str[ing2][string3]'` in which case I would expect to get `['string1', 'str[ing2', 'string3']`. In this case you can use this: https://jsfiddle.net/pt8e2p5w/1/

```
var s = 'string1[str[ing2][string3]'
var matches = ['']

var open = false
for (i in s) {
    if (s[i] == '[' && !open) {
        matches.push('')
        open = true
    } else if (s[i] == ']' && open) {
        open = false
    } else {
        matches[matches.length - 1] += s[i]
    }
}

console.log(matches)
```

outputs: ``

```
["string1", "str[ing2", "string3"]
```

Comment: Thank is what I was looking for! The problem with the inner square brackets like `string1[str[ing2]` are not present ever, is an arbitrary string so it will have to be like the format I said.
Thank you!